Ansible create vm playbook error ssl or ssl wrong version
Currently I have a playbook that will create vm by using ansible but encounter two different error depends on the pyvmomi that I used,

if I used pyvmomi(7.0.3) my ansible playbook will get an error
AttributeError: module 'ssl' has no attribute 'wrap_socket
if I used pyvmomi(8.0.2.0.1) my ansible playbook will get an error
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1000)
for information I'm using python version 3.12.1 and ansible version is ansible [core 2.16.12

my playbook look like this:
hostname: localhost:23224
username: test
password: xxxxxx
datacenter: test
cluster: test

vmware_guest:   
  - name: tab
    template: temp_tep
    folder: /test
    state: poweredoff
  ......

